# Click on a submenu with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Someone can help me please?

[menu and page]

[image: 1]

I've tried find_element_by:

**td**: I can't find which is the correct id index;

**xpath**: its xpath change every page refresh;

**class menuItem:** brought the menu above;

**text_link:** no such element: Unable to locate element;

**css td.menuItemSeleccionado:** no such element: Unable to locate element;

**classe menuItemSeleccionado:** no such element: Unable to locate element

Someone has any idea?

Comment: Please share all your code

Comment: Can you confirm that the sub-menu is visible/expanded before you execute `find_element_by_`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided page source the XPath for submenu could be like:

```
"//td[contains(text(), 'Pesquisa Contratos')]"
```

and in order to click it you have to:

- 1 Click (or hover) the parent menu

  There might be a better way to locate the menu item, but you can try to use the
  partial text:

  to click:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
  "//*[contains(text(), 'De Contratos E Cart')]"))).click()
  ```

  to hover:

  ```
  menu_item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
  "//*[contains(text(), 'De Contratos E Cart')]")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu_item ).perform()
  ```
- 2 Wait for the submenu element to be clickable and click it

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
  "//td[contains(text(), 'Pesquisa Contratos')]"))).click()
  ```

---

*imports*

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```